# exterior NEMA 14-50 AND dual GFCI

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, nec

I want to Install an exterior NEMA 14-50 (RV plug) and dual 120V GFCIs. (One on each leg).  The whole thing is fed from a dedicated 50Amp Dual Pole breaker with 6AWG copper.
Is this a proper way to set it up or am I required to get one of the all-in-one RV sub panels?
[image]

[image]

Also, I want to hang both dual gang boxes on a metal purlin buried in concrete near the workshop structure.

Comment: In metal boxes, You must take ground to the box first.  The recep can usually ground via yoke contact.  If not, then pigtail it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not allowed to supply NEMA 5-20R receptacles with a 50A circuit breaker.  **That is dangerous!**

I suggest an additional penetration for the new receptacles, which should be put on a 20A breaker(s).  You probably don't want to stuff additional wire into the conduit that already has the RV circuit going through it.

If you don't think you'll use both the RV receptacle AND the 20A receptacles at the same time, an alternative is to get a portable power distribution box with a 14-50P inlet plug.  These are available for rent at most equipment rental yards that rent generators, too.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  That makes perfect sense now.  I do have one of those portable breakout boxes. I think I will have to  install  the  RV sub panel with individual 20A breakers for the 120v circuits.  Its a lot bigger footprint, and more money but it has everything i need and feeds from 4 wire 50A feeder already planned and addresses this safety issue.

Comment: Feel free to fit an 8-space little CH or QO sub (quite compact), then put the relevant breakers and receptacles  off that. Probably a lot cheaper than an RV sub.

Comment: Also there’s nothing wrong with 2-4 circuits in conduit, however doing so breaks the exception that allows 50A on #8 wire, and would oblige use of #6

Answer (score 2):

You're not required to get a all in one RV Park Panel, but it's much simpler to install for the price. Everything is included, meets code requirements, not really that much more in material costs, less labor to install and is a single point connection. Meaning it's hard to screw up. Much better for a DIY.